# Why is the thermal conductivity of FR4 shown to have two different values? (Based on heat flow direction)

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, heat, thermal

[image]

[Reference](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/understanding-datasheet-thermal-parameters-and-ic-junction-temperatures)

Why would thermal properties of a material (FR4) depend on direction of heat flow?

Comment: Because it's a layered material the properties depend on direction.

Comment: The term to describe this is "anisotropic".  "Isotropic" means "the same in all directions", "anisotropic" means, well, _not_ the same in all directions.  Materials that have built in directions in their construction also have anisotropic properties.

Comment: Not only is the thermal conductivity quite different, but so is the CTE.

Comment: Imagine a cube made of horizontal layers of copper and plastic foam. The copper sheets will conduct from side to side really well; but vertically, the layers of foam have very poor conduction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FR4 is made of several layers of glass fiber mat embedded in epoxy. The glass fibers conduct heat much better than the epoxy that separates the layers.